# Numerical integral cannot be calculated

Tags: numerical-integration

I want to solve $\mu$ and $T$ in this equation system:

[image]

where $g(\omega)=\frac{1}{\mathrm e^{\omega/T}-1}$ , $N_f(\mu,T)=\frac{4\pi}{(2\pi)^3}\int_0^\infty\frac{k^2}{\mathrm{exp}({\frac{k^2-\mu}{T}})+1}\mathrm dk=\frac{-T^{3/2}\mathrm{PolyLog}(\frac{3}{2},-\mathrm e^{\frac{\mu}{T}})}{8\pi^{3/2}}$ and $V$ is given.

I called function $\frac{\partial IM}{\partial \mu}$ as $\mathrm{PIM}$, $\frac{\partial RE}{\partial \mu}$ as $\mathrm{PRE}$ in the code.

`(*define IM*)`

```
IM[T_?NumericQ, V_?NumericQ, μ_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ, ω_?NumericQ]:=-((T V (q^2 - 
    2 (2 μ + ω)) (-Log[
      E^(ω/(2 T)) + E^((q Sqrt[-q^2 + 4 μ + 2 ω])/(
       2 T))] + 
    Log[1 + E^((ω + q Sqrt[-q^2 + 4 μ + 2 ω])/(
      2 T))]))/(π q Sqrt[(-(q^2/4) + μ + ω/2) (-q^2 + 
     4 μ + 2 ω)] (q^2 - 2 (2 + 2 μ + ω))))
```

`(*define PIM*)`

```
PIM[T_?NumericQ, V_?NumericQ, μ_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ, ω_?NumericQ]:=(2 V Sqrt[(q^2 - 2 (2 μ + ω))^2] ((
   4 T (Log[
       E^(ω/(2 T)) + E^((q Sqrt[-q^2 + 4 μ + 2 ω])/(
        2 T))] - 
      Log[1 + E^((ω + q Sqrt[-q^2 + 4 μ + 2 ω])/(
        2 T))]))/(
   q (q^2 - 2 (2 μ + ω))) + ((q^2 - 
      2 (2 + 2 μ + ω)) Sinh[ω/(
     2 T)])/((-q^2 + 4 μ + 2 ω)^(
    3/2) (Cosh[ω/(2 T)] + 
      Cosh[(q Sqrt[-q^2 + 4 μ + 2 ω])/(
       2 T)]))))/(π (q^2 - 2 (2 + 2 μ + ω))^2)
```

`(*define RE*)`

```
RE[T_?NumericQ, V_?NumericQ, μ_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ, ω_?NumericQ]:=1 - (V*8 π)/(2 π)^3*
  NIntegrate[
   Sin[θ]*k^2/(
    1 + k^2)*(1/(
     q^2/2 + 2*k^2 - 2*μ - ω))*(1 - 1/(
      Exp[(q^2/4 + k^2 + q*k*Cos[θ] - μ)/T] + 1) - 1/(
      Exp[(q^2/4 + k^2 - q*k*Cos[θ] - μ)/T] + 1)), {k, 
    0, ∞}, {θ, 0, π}]
```

`(*define PRE*)`

```
PRE[T_?NumericQ, V_?NumericQ, μ_?NumericQ, q_?NumericQ, ω_?NumericQ]:=(-V*8 π)/(2 π)^3*
 NIntegrate[(k^2 Sin[θ] (-2 (4 k^2 + q^2 - 
          2 (2 μ + ω)) (1 + 
          Cosh[(4 k^2 + q^2 - 4 μ)/(4 T)] Cosh[(
            k q Cos[θ])/T]) + 
       8 T (Cosh[(4 k^2 + q^2 - 4 μ)/(4 T)] + 
          Cosh[(k q Cos[θ])/T]) Sinh[(4 k^2 + q^2 - 4 μ)/(
         4 T)]))/((1 + k^2) T (4 k^2 + q^2 - 
       2 (2 μ + ω))^2 (Cosh[(4 k^2 + q^2 - 4 μ)/(
        4 T)] + Cosh[(k q Cos[θ])/T])^2), {k, 
   0, ∞}, {θ, 0, π}]
```

`(*define Nf*)`

```
Nf[μ_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ]:= -((T^(3/2) PolyLog[3/2, -E^((μ/T))])/(8 π^(3/2)))
```

finally,`(*define Np*)`

```
Np[V_?NumericQ, μ_?NumericQ, T_?NumericQ]:=(-4 π)/(2 π)^3*
  NIntegrate[
   q^2/π*1/(E^(ω/T) - 1)*1/(
    1 + (IM[T, V, μ, q, ω]/
      RE[T, V, μ, q, ω])^2)*(
    RE[T, V, μ, q, ω]*PIM[T, V, μ, q, ω] - 
     IM[T, V, μ, q, ω]*PRE[T, V, μ, q, ω])/(RE[
      T, V, μ, 
      q, ω])^2, {ω, -∞, ∞}, {q, 
    0, ∞}] + Nf[μ, T]
```

$q,k,\omega,\mu$ are real values, and $T, V>0$

Now, my problem is that I cannot even get the value of $N_p$, let alone solve the equation.

For example, it takes a very long time to compute `Np[1,1,1]` and then it gave me the message:

```
Throw::sysexc: Uncaught SystemException returned to top level. Can be caught with Catch[…, _SystemException].
```

```
SystemException["MemoryAllocationFailure"]
```

[image]
[image]
Does any one can fix it? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Include a set of reasonable values for all your parameters, and the explicit call that caused the error you see. Have you already troubleshooted each of the functions you defined, i.e. do they all evaluate **without errors** with those same values of the parameters? If not, you will have to fix that first, or you have no hope to make the whole thing work. This is A LOT of code and functions. You need to do some troubleshooting on your own to restrict the origin of the problem. Don't just dump code and ask for it to be fixed.